# Detecting whether a user has created his node profile

Tags: drupal-6

I am working in Jobs website using Drupal 6, and I need a button to prompt new users to create their profile pages.

Is there a built-in way to detect if the user has created a profile?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The  [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module is what you're looking for.  In fact, it comes with that exact rule you're looking for when you install it.